# Trying to center iframe element. Tried solutions in other questions but nothing worked

Tags: html, css, iframe, bootstrap-4

I tried putting it into a div with style="text-align: center;", tried doing display: block;, tried align="center". Nothing I found worked. Below is the code. I might as well include everything I tried.

```html
<div align="center" style="text-align: center;">
    <script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="false"></script><iframe allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0" height="900px" name="donorbox" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="https://donorbox.org/embed/ondecc?default_interval=o" style="min-width: 310px; max-height:none!important margin: 0 auto; display: block;" width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the original

```html
<script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="false"></script><iframe allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0" height="900px" name="donorbox" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="https://donorbox.org/embed/ondecc?default_interval=o" style="min-width: 310px; max-height:none!important" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Also note I'm doing this in Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fixed solution friend, you just had to add `display : flex;` and `justify-content : center;` to `style` attribute of your `div`.

Also, it is not a very good practice to do inline `css`, instead you should always have an exetrnal `css` file.

Here is your solution. Let me know if that is what you wanted :)

```html
<div align="center" style="width : 100%; display : flex; justify-content : center;">
    <script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="false"></script><iframe allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0" height="900px" name="donorbox" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="https://donorbox.org/embed/ondecc?default_interval=o" style="min-width: 310px; max-height:none!important; display: block; margin : 0 auto;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Width of iframe should be less than 100%, else the element will take up the whole available width of its parent element.

```css
div{
  text-align: center;
}

iframe{
   display:blok;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 310px; /* It should not be 100% */ 
   max-height:none!important
}
```

```html
<div>
<script src="https://donorbox.org/widget.js" paypalExpress="false"></script><iframe allowpaymentrequest="" frameborder="0" height="900px" name="donorbox" scrolling="no" seamless="seamless" src="https://donorbox.org/embed/ondecc?default_interval=o"width="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```